# Bootstrap rowlink, still not working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I realise there are quite alot of questions about this particular topic, but I've tried every one of those solutions and they don't quite work. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong, please point it out if you see it.

So I have a Spring MVC app with JSP pages implementing Twitter Bootstrap. In one of those I got a table which gets filled by JSTL `forEach` cycle. This is where I can't seem to get it working. Here's what I got:

```
<table class="table table-hover" data-provides="rowlink">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Last Mod</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="recipe" items='${recipes}'>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/recipes/${recipe.id}">${recipe.inputTitle}</a></td>
                <td>${recipe.author}</td>
                <td>${recipe.timestamp}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="/recipes/${recipe.id}"><i class="icon-list icon-white"></i> Detalhe</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What this does is basically slapping a link onto the 1st field (Title) and it doesn't get the whole row clickable. Also, I would like if it was possible not to appear link-like, if you know what I mean.

I've tried `<tbody data-provides="rowlink">` also, and pretty much every kind of combination I've seen on all the answers that exist here on SO.

What am I missing ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Could some1 just point out what is the correct way to do this ? Maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to @SlavaSemushin , I've managed to get the entire row clickable, adding `class="rowlink"  to the`` inside the loop:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-provides="rowlink">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Last Mod</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="recipe" items='${recipes}'>
                <tr class="rowlink">
                <a href="/recipes/${recipe.id}">
                    <a href="/recipes/${recipe.id}">${recipe.inputTitle}</a></td>
                    <td>${recipe.author}</td>
                    <td>${recipe.timestamp}</td>

                </a>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've tried to add `class="nolink"` to the `<td>` where the link is given and also tried adding it to the `<tr>` where I put `class="rowlink"`, but it didn't work either way.

So the problem about having the entire row clickable is solved, I just want to remove the link highlight on the first table field.

Comment: 'rowlink' is part of Jasny: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#rowlink - Did you include the required .js for this?

Comment: yes, I included the required .js as well as the .css in there.

Comment: Try to add `class="rowlink"` to `<tr>` tag inside loop.

Comment: Yes, that worked as far as having the entire row clickable. Still, it's not entirely as I needed. The first field of the table is still highlighted as a link, and I didn't want that. Gonna edit the post with the new snippet.

Comment: Late here. Don't know for the content, i guess the forEach is run on server? If not, try to do: var theTable = $('#your-table'); theTable.rowlink(theTable.data());